# Object destructing resulting in 'never' type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, object-destructuring

My code is as follows:

```
export function testGraph({ id = 0, name = "test", nodes = [] }): Graph {
  if (nodes.length === 0) {
    const dummyNode = testNode({});
    return new Graph(id, name, [dummyNode]);
  }

  return new Graph(id, name, nodes);
}
export function testDatabase({ id = 0, name = "test", graphs = [] }): Database {
  if (graphs.length === 0) {
    const dummyGraph = testGraph({ nodes: new Array(new Node(0)) });
    return new Database(id, name, [dummyGraph]);
  }

  return new Database(id, name, graphs);
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Type 'Node[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'Node' is not assignable to type 'never'.

    40     const dummyGraph = testGraph({ nodes: new Array(new Node(0)) });
                                          ~~~~~
```

I can't seem to understand why this is automatically inferring 'never' type. I tried explicitly declaring the type but to no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This discussion on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18687) puts some light on the issue:

> This is caused by the combination of `strict` and `noImplicitAny: false`. In general we expect that if `strict` is on, `noImplicitAny` is also on; this particular set of settings will expose some odd behavior. If you had both on, you'd see an error about the `[]` being implicitly `any[]`; if both were off; we'd use control flow analysis and treat the array as a `number[]` after the push(1);.
>
> The particular combination ( `"strict": true, "noImplicitAny": false,` ) of settings means that we don't allow ourselves to use control flow analysis or allow the array to be implicitly `any[]`, so `never[]` is the only remaining allowable option.
>
> I'd recommend turning off `strict` if you're not going to have `noImplicitAny` on.

So, this may be a possible way out

```js
export function testGraph({ id = 0, name = "test", nodes = [] as Array<Node> }): Graph {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`nodes = []`. An array of what?

`[]` is never enough to for typescript to infer an array type, and is inferred as `never[]` in this particular case. So, typically, you just provide a type for the whole destructured object, and include the proper array type:

```
export function testGraph({
    id = 0,
    name = "test",
    nodes = []
}: {
    id?: number,
    name?: string,
    nodes?: Node[]
}): Graph {
    //...
}
```

---

Or infer from the caller by using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

```
export function testGraph<T>({
    id = 0,
    name = "test",
    nodes = []
}: {
    id?: number,
    name?: string,
    nodes?: T[]
}): Graph<T> {
    //...
}
```

Note that you'll probably want to make `Graph` generic as well, so that the node type you pass to `testGraph` can be reflected in the `Graph`'s nodes as well.

That might look something like:

```
class Graph<T> {
    constructor(id: number, name: string, nodes: T[]) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to tell the compiler to infer the type from the call?